# Xcode internal error when a certain line of code is insert

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been hunting down the source of this bug for a couple hours and I've found the line that causes it. The error is Xcode saying "An internal error occurred. source editor functionality limited" and all the syntax highlighting stops working. The error occurs whenever I typed about five or six keys or hit enter a couple of times.

After commenting and uncommenting code to find the problem, it turns out to be this line:

```
snapshot.value["string here"]
```

The weirdest thing is that I'm using that code here

```
        // query server for a snapshot of current user's schedule
        FirRef.child("\(user!.school)/students").queryOrderedByChild("email")
            .queryEqualToValue("(userEmail!)").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
            if let data = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]
            {
                // create new user model
                let newUser = UserModel()
                newUser.email = data["email"] as! String
                newUser.school = data["school"] as! String
                newUser.userId = data["userId"] as! String
                newUser.title = ""
                newUser.firstName = data["firstName"] as! String
                newUser.lastName = data["lastName"] as! String
                newUser.firstPeriod = data["firstPeriod"] as! String
                newUser.secondPeriod = data["secondPeriod"] as! String
                newUser.thirdPeriod = data["thirdPeriod"] as! String
                newUser.fourthPeriod = data["fourthPeriod"] as! String
                newUser.fifthPeriod = data["fifthPeriod"] as! String
                newUser.sixthPeriod = data["sixthPeriod"] as! String
                newUser.seventhPeriod = data["seventhPeriod"] as! String


            }
        })
```

and theres no issue but when I use this

```
// query server for snapshot of any teachers in the user's school
FirRef.child("\(user!.school)/teachers").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

    // iterate through all teachers found
    for teacher in snapshot.children
    {
        // as soon as this line is put in
        // Xcode wants to break itself
        let thisBreaksStuff = teacher.value["exampleValue"]
    }
```

The code runs perfectly well and retrieves the data I want from the server with no problem. But Xcode just doesn't like it.

Yes I have cleaned the project multiple times, restarted Xcode, restarted my computer. I've even deleted the derived data from Xcode as some people say to do

Comment: Have you sent a bug report to Apple?

Comment: I haven't yet no. But I will